# How do TCP/IP and HTTP work together?

Tags: http, networking, tcp

I'm playing with Wireshark to debug some IoT home automation projects I'm working on. I think I'd benefit from understanding more about how HTTP and TCP/IP are actually working. Most explanations I'm finding describe HTTP as "riding on top of" TCP/IP, but I'm asking more specifically about what is actually being sent.

Here's an example of a client/server interaction I captured:

```
Client: [SYN]
Server: [SYN, ACK]
Client: [ACK]
```

If I understand so far, they've now successfully established a TCP connection. The next capture, though, shows me

```
Client: POST /whatever
Server: 200 OK
```

Okay now I'm lost. Examining that capture shows me that I have an Ethernet, IP, TCP, and HTTP layer all in one frame. Is it actually as simple as the client adding a bunch of text after the TCP packet ends and squirting those extra bytes over to the router? Which, presumably, then parses the TCP/IP out and forwards it accordingly? This is the source of my confusion. By "rides on top of" is it meant (in a physical sense) that HTTP is just a series of bytes that are sent in the same frame, after the TCP packet? Is the HTTP in this case considered to be the payload of the TCP/IP?

And of course to finish

```
Server: [FIN, ACK]
Client: [ACK]
Client: [FIN, ACK]
Server: [ACK]
//In this case the server terminates the connection.
```

Edit: A commenter below asked a question which makes me feel as if I haven't been very clear about what I'm asking.

Imagine that I could stand between my client and the server (or perhaps it would be more accurate to stand between my client and the router and again between the router and the server). Ignoring the considerations when one has to physically send raw data over a physical medium (checksums, error correction codes, etc), what would the actual traffic look like, with respect to time? Would I see bytes for an ethernet layer followed by bytes for an ip layer, tcp, http, and so on?

Comment: HTTP is just data to TCP, but I don't know why you keep saying '*after* the TCP packet'. Data sent over TCP is sent *in* TCP packets.

Comment: I mean that at some point, my client (a sensor) is just sending a byte stream over the air to the router. The router interprets those byes and does something with them (forwards them to the server). That stream of bytes can in interpreted in some useful way. If you were to examine that byte stream one byte at a time as it's being sent out of the sensor's antenna, would it look like [Ethernet][IP][TCP][HTTP]? (Excepting, of course, what I'd assume to be a lot of error correction codes, checksums, etc.)

Comment: If you are sending from an antenna, it would be Wi-Fi, and the frames would be Wi-Fi frames, not ethernet frames. Wi-Fi and ethernet are two completely different data-link protocols.

Comment: Alright I have some fundamental misunderstanding of how all these protocols work together, then. The wireshark captures I'm looking at are all capturing on a WiFI interface, but show "Encapsulation type: Ethernet". I was trying to ask what's being sent, disregarding the actual medium. I.e. a all this TCP/IP & HTTP data still needs to arrive at the router, right? I'm not so much concerned about whether that's done over an ethernet cable or WiFi but what it looks like when it gets there.

Comment: What arrives at the physical interface of the router is the frame. What the router itself sees is the packet because it strips off the frame. I explained that in my answer. Based on the destination layer-3 address the router sends the packet to a different interface, and it builds a frame for the next network, and that network can use a completely different layer-1/2 protocol.

Comment: 'Would it look like [Ethernet][IP][TCP][HTTP]?' The only possible answer to this is 'yes'. All of the above, depending on how you snooped it. You still haven't explained 'after the TCP packet'.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The network layers use abstraction and encapsulation. The lower layers encapsulate the higher layers.

- The Application layer can have its own protocols, e.g. HTTP. HTTP
  communicates with HTTP on the target device, and it is a protocol
  that transfers the application data (HTML).
- The Transport layer (layer 4) encapsulates the application datagrams,
  and it communicates with the same Transport layer protocol on the
  target device. Some transport protocols have guarantees and create
  connections for reliability, e.g. TCP (segments), but some are
  connectionless with no guarantees, e.g. UDP (datagrams). The purpose
  of this layer is to get the application data from one application to
  another application. Some transport protocols use addressing (ports)
  to accomplish this, and some use something else, or nothing at all.
- The Network layer encapsulates the transport protocol datagrams into
  packets, and it communicates with the target device network protocol.
  The purpose of this layer is to get packets from a device on one
  network to a device on another network. Routers use the addressing
  information in the packet headers to accomplish this (IPv4, IPX,
  IPv6, AppleTalk, etc. addresses).
- The Data Link layer encapsulates the network packets into frames, and
  it communicates with the data link of a device on the same network.
  The purpose of this layer is to get frames to another device on
  the same network (PC printer, router, etc.). Some data-link protocols
  use addressing (IEEE protocols use MAC addressing, either 48-bit or
  64-bit MAC addresses), some use other addressing (frame relay uses
  DLCIs, ATM uses VPI/VCI, etc.), and some use no addressing (PPP only
  has two devices, so it needs no addressing). The protocol can change
  as the encapsulated packet is sent from one network to another
  on its way to the destination device. Routers strip off the frame and
  discard it as they forward the packets from one network to another,
  creating a new frame to encapsulate the packet for the new network.
- The physical layer (layer 1) converts the frames of the Data Link
  layer (layer-2) into the "bits on the wire."

The destination device performs the reverse of the above, delivering the application data to the destination application.

Because of the abstraction and encapsulation at each layer, you can mix and match different protocols at different layers. For example, ethernet can carry any number of network protocols (IPv4, IPX, IPv6, AppleTalk, etc.) without knowing or caring what is in the payload of the ethernet frame. Conversely, IP doesn't know or care which data-link protocol (ethernet, Wi-Fi, token ring, PPP, frame relay, etc.) is carrying it.

Your web browser uses HTTP to communicate the data (HTML) between it and the web server. HTTP uses TCP to transport it to the web server. The web browser will request that TCP assign it a TCP address (port). The web server likely uses the well-known TCP port 80 for HTTP, and TCP will segment the stream of data from the application into TCP segments (do not confuse this with IPv4 fragmentation). TCP will create a connection with TCP on the OS of the web server, and TCP guarantees that the segments will arrive, and that the data presented to the destination application will be complete, and in order.

TCP can theoretically use any network-layer protocol, but in practice it only uses IPv4 or IPv6. IP will encapsulate the TCP segments into IP packets.

IP will use the data-link protocol of the interface through which that packets will be sent. On a PC, this is most likely either ethernet or Wi-Fi, but it can be something else like PPP. The data-link protocol will encapsulate the packets into frames for the data-link protocol. Each data-link protocol has a different frame format. If the destination device is on the same network, the frames are addressed and delivered directly to the destination. If the destination is on a different network, the frames are addressed and delivered to the gateway (router) configured in the source OS.

The interface will encode the bits in the frame and signal on the medium of the interface.

Comment: Thank you for this really detailed answer. It helped a lot. To confirm I understood correctly, it could theoretically be that my HTTP POST is broken into several TCP segments, which are then encapsulated by lower layers, sent, and reconstructed on the server. i.e. when the server's transport layer software has determined all that particular session's TCP packets have been received, the HTTP is reconstructed from these segments and passed to the relevant application?

Comment: Yes. But remember that HTTP is also a protocol for transferring application data. The application data it transfers is actually HTML.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. And then because every layer is agnostic of the others, this architecture makes it easy to swap out HTTP for FTP or SSH, without having to design anything new underneath to deliver them. Exactly the same way you can communicate over ethernet or wifi without having to change any of the layers above.

Comment: is it correct to say that HTTP is just the format of a string? That string being the request (or the response)

Comment: No, HTTP is a protocol. Its data, HTML, consists of strings in a particular format (language).