# How does physically TCP send and receive data?

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm currently learning about Layer 4 in the tcp/ip model. All of the sources of information that I have stumbled on gave me the following explanation about how the TCP protocol is implemented by the computer: "It establishes connection between the application and the computer via network sockets and transporting the required data between a specific port which is a direct function to the transmitted data."

I found this explanation very vague considering the fact that it does not give any info about how it is actually transporting the data in between the ports, so my question is as follows:

How physically the data is transmitted between layer 5 and 4 using TCP and is this transmission limited only to programs or processes inside the computer?

Comment: Does this help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol ? or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Comment: I have already read that, this is more detailed but steal uses the term "establishing a connection" and doing so not referring to how it is being done.

Comment: I think the question is flawed, TCP is not a physical layer but a transport layer so I am not sure the premise of the question is correct.  If you want to know the physical side of the communication, check Layer 1 in the links I posted - if you want to know about how TCP works, check the other link.  Establishing a connection, on Layer 4 is different than on Layer 1 -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is layer 4.  You need to look at layers 1-3 of the OSI model to understand how it gets around.  Layer 1 would discuss how electrical (or light) impulses are encoded on a wire which would be the physical part.  All the layers above are various kinds of abstractions of how those impulses (0's and 1's) are interpreted.

Basically data isn't transported between layers.  Each layer is enbedded in the layer below it.  In other words layer 2 has a payload which holds layer 3 and so forth.  So as the data moves up the stack each layer is removed.  So layer 4 wouldn't see any of the encapulation for layers 1-3, but would have layers 5+ in its payload which it would pass along once it handles and stripes off its part.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for you answer, I have yet decided if it answers my question but it gives me more understanding for sure. To answer my question completely I have a more specific one: so once the data is stripped off and layer 4 is being handled how is the computer handls it and transport the data between the application and the ports?

Comment: @rovolution, it does not specifically answer your question, but you may be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46795235/3745413) that explains the layers.

Comment: @Ron Maupin thank you very much, this answer was helpful but it raises some more sub questions as one might say, like: How are the data grams from the application being gathered to the process that reforms the packet?

Comment: There is a daemon (basically low-level code) that sits on the physical device (e.g. ethernet port, wifi chip, etc).  It reads in the data (basically just a block of memory).  That daemon will typically handle the first 3 layers.  An application will listen on a port which basically tells the daemon when data comes in on that port (layer 4) give it to me.

Comment: @user2199860 Are you referring to the listening application as a separate one (not the one that sends the data) which tells the daemon when data is coming in? (btw a link about it so I can read more would be appreciated)

Comment: Essentially there is a user-space application listening for data from a particular port and there is a kernel space daemon/driver/service which handles all data being sent to that computer.  All of this is for one side of the conversation.  A similar setup exists on the other computer in the conversation.  

Here is a link to help visualize:
https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/ccna-study-guide/data-encapsulation-and-de-encapsulation-explained.html