# Is it really possible to send multiple http requests at the same time with these conditions

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, desktop-application

Let's imagine we have the following resources (the blue arrow is the flow direction of http requests and the green one is the flow of http responses):

[image: resources]

The "Desktop App" sends **multiple http requests at the same time** concurrently using threads and waits for responses but, my concern is that **I heard**, that **the router** sends the **IP packets one after the other** and my goal is to send the http requests at the same time.

**Question:**
Is it technically possible to send multiple requests at the same time with a single NIC and one Router connected to the internet?

Comment: A network interface serializes a frame (an IP packet is the payload in a frame, a TCP segment is the payload in an IP packet, etc., see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46795235/3745413) about that), and sends the frame one bit at a time on the wire. The frame monopolizes the interface until it is completely sent. Frames from different processes can be interleaved in a queue waiting to be sent, but networking is essentially serial. It happens so fast that it appears to be simultaneous.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks a lot for the comment, so, it is possible but with a fraction of milliseconds of delay among requests, right?

Comment: It really boils down to the difference between circuit switching and packet switching. Circuit-switched networks, e.g. the original telephone network, monopolize a path for the entire conversation, while packet switching was an improvement by breaking conversations into packets and only monopolizing the path for a tiny amount of time, allowing other conversations to also use the path for tiny periods of time. It appears that the path is simultaneously shared, even though it is really only shared over a larger period of time.

Answer (score 2):

The router might handle one packet after one another, but that does not mean the the router also waits for the response to the current packet before sending the next packet. So it definitely is capable of sending multiple requests and handling their response "at the same time" - at least from your application's perspective.

Some components that are taking part in transmitting data over a network might impose limits on how many requests can be sent in parallel. For the most part, your application will not notice this. Of course, if you have lots of simultaneous requests, you might experience longer response times because requests are queued, but no errors as long as you don't have a very large amount of parallel requests.